# ncurses can't display element on x y position from structure

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses

I'm trying to display an robot with ncurses.
When x & y are printed with printf all is ok, but with `mvwprintw(window, x, y, "a");` nothing is displaying.
What is the problem?

File: view.

```c
#include <ncurses.h>
#include "config.c"
#include "arena.c"

void create_window(){
    robot robots[NUMBER_ROBOTS];

    create_robots(robots);
    initscr();
    raw();
    noecho();

    WINDOW * window = newwin(TERM_HEIGHT, TERM_WIDTH, 0, 0);

    refresh();

    box(window, 0,0); 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_ROBOTS; i++)
    {   
        //to_string(robots[i]);
        int x = get_posx(robots[i]);
        int y = get_posy(robots[i]);

        printf("X%d Y%d\n", x, y);

        wrefresh(window);
        mvwprintw(window, x, y, "a");

    }
    wrefresh(window);
    getch(); 
    endwin();
}

void launch(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   

    create_window(); 

}
```

File robot.h

```c
typedef struct robot{
  int state;
  char id[1];
  double posX,posY;
  double posXo,posYo;
  int speed;
  int life;
  missile missiles[2];  
} robot ;
```

File arena.c

```c
int get_posx(robot r){
    return (r.posX*TERM_WIDTH)/WIDTH;
}

int get_posy(robot r){
    return (r.posY*TERM_HEIGHT)/HEIGHT;
}
```

Screen of the execution: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r1Vb.png)
There are any "a" displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few possibilities:

- the call to `mvwprintw` interchanges the x/y coordinates (so it will take that rather large *x* value and make that a row-number, losing any text written when it goes out of range)
- the screenshot doesn't show the bottom of the box (perhaps that `TERM_HEIGHT` is incorrect, aggravating the problem with the coordinates)
- the `printf` gets in the way, confusing curses about where the cursor really is
- the `getch` should be a `wgetch(window)`, just in case (I don't see any) there were pending updates to `stdscr`.